# How to make a network plot using a "from-to-dataframe"?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame with two columns. The first column indicates from where someone comes and the second column includes where someone goes. Like in this example: Someone comes from "a" and goes to "a", "b" or "c". Is there a way in R to plot the network that results of this data using the following data frame? Or has the data frame be transformed further to be able to plot it?

```
from = c("a")
to = rep(c("a","b","c"),times=c(2,3,5))
data=cbind(from,to)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might be able to do it with a sankey plot or an alluvial plot. have you tried any plotting functions, if so can you share your plot code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot this using the igraph package like so:

```
library(igraph)
graph <- graph_from_edgelist(data)
plot(graph)
```

[image]

Comment: igraph also supports other ploting styles, you might want to read about it in the manual: (https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/#P)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chord diagram as well.
Sample data:

```
from = c("a")
to = rep(c("a","b","c"),times=c(2,3,5))
data=cbind(from,to)
```

Sample code:

```
library(circlize)

  cols <- hcl.colors(4, "Temps")    

chordDiagram(data,
         col = cols,
         transparency = 0.1,
         link.lwd = 1,    # Line width
         link.lty = 1,    # Line type
         link.border = 1) # Border color

circos.clear()
```

Plot:

[image]